# Move column left to right using jquery , first column should be constant

Tags: jquery

I Have Dynamic table in that i have to add Columns through coladdButton.
then Dynamically added columns i need move Left and Right using jquery.

Note: First column should be constant. It should not move anywhere.

From second column to nth column i can move left to right and Right to left.

I have tried with Draggable plugin.
please Col add Sourcecode:

$("#colAdd").on("click",function(){

```
var colsize = $("#testDtbl th").length;
var rowsize = $("#testDtbl tr").length;
if($("#renCol").val().trim() == "" || $("#renCol").val() == null){
    return false;
}
$("#row0").append('<th bgcolor="#CCCCCC">'+$("#renCol").val()+'</th> <input type="hidden" name="cellVal[0]['+colsize+']" value="'+$("#renCol").val()+'" >');

for(var i=1; i<=rowsize; i++){

    $("#row"+i).append('<td><input type="text" name=cellVal['+i+']['+colsize+'] /></td>');

    '<td><input type="checkbox" />';
}
```

});

Comment: Update your question with the code

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to drag the columns?

Comment: Please share some code as well